# How do I change the value of a variable stored in another file?

Tags: python, variables, python-import

I've been working on a text based role-playing game made purely with Python. I have a file tree like this :-

```
Parent Folder
    Directory abc
        File A
    

    Directory xyz
        File B
```

Imagine there's a variable named userInventory which is a list, stored in File A.

```
userInventory = ["hp_potion", "pod_token", "broken_cup"]
```

What I wanna do is to import File A in File B, and then update the value of userInventory which is in File A by appending something to it in File B.

If I try to do something like this in B :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert('../Path/to/File/A)
import A

A.userInventory.append("bronze_sword")
```

Then it imports the file and actually updates the value of userInventory, but once the program in File B ends, the changes made to userInventory are declined and the variable reverts back to normal. This happens because it never really changes the value of userInventory which is stored in File A. What Python does is to assign the new value **temporarily** which exists until the program is running in B.

> My Question is : How do I change its value completely which then can be used further in other files?

I mean, when you're developing a game in multiple files, you need some variables that will define some of the user stats and the game and are stored in a different file for easy access all over the parent folder.

Comment: Python only ever reads python files as text files and creates objects in memory from the instructions it finds. It never writes back to source files. It sounds like you need a database.

Comment: Precisely. Like I added in the end, one needs a file or a database, whatever, to store some data which can be used all over the Parent folder. I don't know if that's possible. Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider that python is for logic, not really for persisting data.

Which is why you can load your variable from the file A, it goes in memory, and when you modify it, it only changes it in memory and will not get persisted.

To persist your data, you can use any of [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), or [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), which are intended to store/retrieve data.

Also, I doubt you want to use `sys.path`, I've never needed it myself and it looks like it you need relative importing.

Comment: Got it. But sys.path is kind of needed, python only tries to find the file in the directory where the import has been called. As in this case, there's no 'File A' in xyz so you need to tell the program where to find it else or it will return 'moduleNotFound' error.

Comment: In your hierarchy, what do you consider the root ? Once you have figures that out, everything should be importable from the root using `from .abc.ABC import xyz` to import at the same level, and from a subdirectory using `from ..abc.ABC import xyz`. If you need `sys.path` something is wrong with your hierarchy.

Comment: I mean, yes. But I do like to use sys method because it seems much more easy to me when you want to access multiple files that are stored in the same different directory.